# Move playa field within a Matrix field

Tags: matrix, playa

So our current setup has a channel with a playa field. This worked well so far BUT now we need to store specific values for each relationship (eg: The related field will need a catalogue number, specific price etc so each child relationship can have unique values as well).

From the top of my head this could be achieved by creating a new matrix/grid field in the same channel with all those unique columns (playa relationship field, catalogue number, price, etc).

My questions is, would that be the best solution for this issue? If so, I'm guessing that a MySQL query with the right format should do the job?

Cheers,
Alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct - it'll have to be a Matrix field, as I believe that Playa is not compatible with the Grid.

You'll have to:

- find all of the entries in `exp_playa_relationships` which use the old `parent_field_id`
- change each row to the new `parent_field_id`
- insert a new entry in `exp_matrix_data` with the correct `entry_id` and `field_id`
- add the new `parent_col_id` and `parent_row_id` (which will be `0`) to your existing `exp_playa_relationships` row

Comment: Hi Derek. We've followed your approach and everything seems to be working that way. Thanks heaps!